# Rails HTML not changing when I push to production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a rails app hosted on ubuntu and served with Apache2 and Passenger. I am having issues getting changes in one of my views to actually reflect in the server. I am not talking about css but the generated html is not changing. I am at a loss for what to do. I am using turbolinks -- though im not talking about css. I have a new.js.erb file that isn't rendering on load and I have changes to a partial view that aren't rendering on restart either. All of this works in development.

production.rb

```
config.cache_classes = true
config.eager_load = true
config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
config.serve_static_files = true
config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
config.assets.compile = true
config.assets.digest = true
config.log_level = :debug
config.i18n.fallbacks = true
config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new
config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
```

restarting the server with `passenger-config restart-app`

**Edit 1**
edit.js.erb that will not load

```
$("#deal_<%= escape_javascript @deal.id.to_s %>").fadeOut("slow", function() {
    var div = $("<%= escape_javascript render partial: 'edit_deal', locals: {deal: @deal} %>").hide();
    div.find('.save_deal_link').first().click(function(event) {
        $(this).closest('form').submit();
        event.preventDefault();
        // Prevent link from following its href
    });
    $("#deal_<%= escape_javascript @deal.id.to_s %>").replaceWith(div);
    div.fadeIn("slow");
});
```

When I attempt to access this code directly by following baseurl/accounts/2/deals/1/edit.js I get error `422` which seems to just be a standard CORS error from the log. I think a better clue to the problem is that in a partial `_deal.html.erb` the changes are not being reflected on the production environment.

**Edit 2**
I am noticing that the click handler is not firing for the link that makes the ajax request, and the production server appears to be serving the new.js.erb -- it's just changes in the view(.html.erb) are not seemingly getting served no matter how many times i upload the views folder

Comment: Are you specifically rendering that file in the view? As in <%= render 'new.js.erb' %> ? Also, is your new.js.erb file being run from a controller action such as an ajax request? If that's the case have you tried running the request that would tell the controller to run the .js.erb file?

Comment: No i have an ajax request that tries to render that. But it's also not taking the changes to html.erb

Comment: How does your new.js.erb code look? Are you correctly escaping javascript to render the partial?

Comment: Yeah, it's all escaped -- it works fine in development and on local machines. It's rendering nothing as if the file doesn't exist. Also it was edit.js.erb -- new works. Ill add code

Comment: Oh... oh my. I found the problem. I changed the location of the partial from /accounts/_deal.html.erb to /application/_deal.html.erb and forgot to remove the old one on production. Doh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the location of the partial from /accounts/_deal.html.erb to /application/_deal.html.erb and forgot to remove the old one on production.